# Diferença entre Classe modelo e Classe gerada em um Webservice

Tags: java, web-service

Estou tendo problemas ao gerar um webservice. 
Tenho minha Lib com as classes de modelo: Endereco, Cidade e Cliente.
Tenho também uma Lib com as classes DAO para controlar o acesso aos dados para as classes de modelo: EnderecoDAO, ClienteDAO, CidadeDAO.

Na classe Endereco.java, tenho dois atributos privados que são:

```
private Cidade cidade;
private Cliente cliente;
```

O problema é que ao gerar um Webservice que utilizo como um controle entre back e front end, o código gerado para a classe Endereco fica com o seguinte aspecto:

```
private lib.modelo.Cliente cliente;
private int cidade;
```

Não consigo entender nem achar o "x" da qustao para esse problema. Já tentei refazer as classes, alterar na mão o código gerado pelo webservice sem sucesso.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Problema foi resolvido.

O que faltava era atualizar os arquivos .jar do classpath do meu servidor apache.